# Como Insertar html al DOM y acceder a el con JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente formulario para buscar un registro de producto en la base de datos mediante codigo

```
 <div id="divSearch" class="row div-head-buttons">
   <div id="divBarCode" class="col-sm-6 d-sm-none d-md-block">
     <form id="barCodeForm" name="barCodeForm" method="POST">
       <input type="text" autofocus="" id="ordet_productCode" name="ordet_productCode" value="">
       <input hidden type="submit" form="barCodeForm">
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Los elementos de este formulario los manipulo con jQuery

```
// formulario de busqueda por codigo, el de referencia es igual    
$("#barCodeForm").on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        var codeIn = $("#ordet_productCode").val();
          $.get('PosProductName.php', {
            "prd_id": 0,
            "prd_code": codeIn
          }, function (dataGroup) {
            if (dataGroup) {
              $('#groupName').html(dataGroup);
          } else {
              $('#groupName').html('Sin Dato');
          }
      });
    });
```

Cuando el formulario esta en la pagina al cargarla, el codigo funciona bien, se ingresa el codigo se presiona enter y muestra la informacion necesaria. Por razones de diseño necesito mostrar otro formulario en el mismo sitio para buscar otro tipo de registro (referencia) para lo cual elimine el formulario de la pagina html y deje `divSearch` vacio para insertar el formulario segun sea el caso

```
  <div id="divSearch" class="row div-head-buttons">
  </div>
```

Asi cargo uno u otro formulario con jQuery

```
   //  form code    
   function formCode() {
      $("#divSearch").empty();
      $.get('ParkFormSearch.php', {
       "form": "code",
      }, function (dataform) {
        $('#divSearch').html(dataform);
      });
    }
    
    // form ref
    function formRef() {
      $("#divSearch").empty();
      $.get('ParkFormSearch.php', {
       "form": "ref",
      }, function (dataform) {
        $('#divSearch').html(dataform);
      });
    }
```

los formularios estan en php

```
$form = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'form', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if ($form == 'code') {
    $formSearch = '
      <div id="divBarCode" class="col-sm-6 d-sm-none d-md-block">
        <form id="barCodeForm" name="barCodeForm" method="POST">
          <input type="text" autofocus="" id="ordet_productCode" name="ordet_productCode" value="">
          <input hidden type="submit" form="barCodeForm">
        </form>
      </div>
    ';
} else {
    $formSearch = '
      <div id="divBarRef" class="col-sm-6 d-sm-none d-md-block">
        <form id="barRefForm" name="barCodeForm" method="POST">
          <input type="text" autofocus="" id="ordet_productRef" name="ordet_productRef" value="">
          <input hidden type="submit" form="barRefForm">
        </form>
     </div>
    ';
}

echo $formSearch;
```

Los formularios, visualmente, se cargan bien y cambian correctamente, pero es aqui donde comienza el problema puesto que los elementos de los formularios no se pueden manipular con jQuery, es como si no existieran, lo he intentado con las fuciones `html, append y load` pero ninguna me da resultado.

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. Tampoco entiendo por qué creas los formularios en PHP si parece que realmente no necesitan nada del servidor. Explica con más claridad lo que quieres hacer y dinos qué justifica aquí el uso de PHP aparte de crear confusión en la organización del código.

Comment: A. Cedano, realmente trate de simplificar el codigo para mostrar... lo que quiero exponer, es que el formulario nativo en la pagina ´html´ funciona bien, pero cuando lo inserto despues que la pagina esta cargada jquery ya no reconoce los elementos y no los puedo manipular

Comment: Es que no explicas bien el problema en la pregunta. ¿Por qué los dos formularios? ¿Uno debe mostrarse solamente en ciertas ocasiones? ¿qué ocasiones? ¿qué evento debe provocar que el segundo formulario se muestre? Esto no tiene nada que ver con PHP, puedes hacerlo todo desde el cliente (Javascript/jQuery) escuchando los eventos. Lo de PHP sólo agrega confusión en tu código al menos para resolver lo que expones. Y si los formularios no son dinámicos, entonces muéstralos mediante código HTML simplemente, ¿por qué liarte con jQuery y con PHP para algo que debería estar fijo en la página?

Comment: Como te decia, el codigo esta muy recortado puesto que la informacion que trae el archivo php no es relevante para la pregunta. No son dos formulario en reallidad son 5 y solo tienen un campo, estos formularios deben ir en una una sola `row` de 4 `cols` en la parte supeerior de la pagina. Cada uno se muestra segun la seleccion del cliente que la hace presionando unos botones cada boton ejecuta una funcion en jquery la cual muestra el formulario que corresponda y un listado de los registros encontrados (por esto el PHP). Debo incluirlos todos en `html` y los oculto o muestro segun sea el caso?

Comment: Para que te formes un criterio y no te hagas lío, hay aspectos básicos que conviene comprender: Javascript (jQuery, Ajax), HTML están del lado del cliente, o sea el contenido de la página que ve cada usuario y PHP está del lado del servidor (base de datos y otros...). Teniendo eso claro, usa el servidor únicamente cuando necesites datos que están en el servidor, para todo lo demás, usa el cliente. A veces hay contenido mezclado: cliente y servidor. Pues igual, usa el servidor para traer aquellos datos que no tienes en el cliente, luego con los datos a mano construye todo desde el cliente.

Comment: En el caso que expones, creo que debes escuchar los eventos que ocurren en el cliente (por evento se entiende clicks en un botón, cambios en un `select`, etc)... Luego, en la escucha de esos eventos, muestra lo que tengas que mostrar. ¿Qué necesitas mostrar algo que está en el servidor, pues ve al servidor a buscarlo (usando Ajax), entonces Ajax te traerá al cliente esos datos y los tendrás a mano para mostrarlos en el cliente. No sé si me he explicado. Todo el lío que tienes, me parece, es debido a que no tienes claro los conceptos cliente/servidor. Si estás perdido en eso, lo estarás en todo

Comment: Lo tengo claro.

Comment: No me parece que lo tengas tan claro. Al menos no queda reflejado así en tu código. Como ya dije, tirar de código PHP para construir un formulario que no aporta nada del servidor no tiene sentido. Si lo tienes claro, entonces expón la pregunta  explicando en primer lugar de forma sencilla lo que quieres hacer y luego explica cómo estás intentando hacerlo, qué errores tienes, etc. A mi me parece que es todo confuso y eso se debe a que no tienes claros ciertos conceptos que he intentado explicarte.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Esto sucede pues al limpiar el div y crearlo de nuevo, los triggers ya no existen pues el elemento fue creado apenas en el dom (aunque tenga el mismo id, el elemento es diferente)

Entonces, al recargarlos es necesario volver a asignarle sus listeners para que funcione de nuevo ya qu el elemento como dije, es nuevo

intenta estos cambios:

```
function activaCambios(){

$("#barCodeForm").on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        var codeIn = $("#ordet_productCode").val();
          $.get('PosProductName.php', {
            "prd_id": 0,
            "prd_code": codeIn
          }, function (dataGroup) {
            if (dataGroup) {
              $('#groupName').html(dataGroup);
          } else {
              $('#groupName').html('Sin Dato');
          }
      });
    });


}

   //  form code    
   function formCode() {
      $("#divSearch").empty();
      $.get('ParkFormSearch.php', {
       "form": "code",
      }, function (dataform) {
        $('#divSearch').html(dataform);
        activaCambios(); /// COLOCA DE NUEVO EL TRIGGER ON SUBMIT
      });
    }
    
    // form ref
    function formRef() {
      $("#divSearch").empty();
      $.get('ParkFormSearch.php', {
       "form": "ref",
      }, function (dataform) {
        $('#divSearch').html(dataform);
        activaCambios(); /// COLOCA DE NUEVO EL TRIGGER ON SUBMIT
      });
    }
```

Espero que esto solucione tu duda.

Saludos